# pm2 works fine on port 80, but no other ports are accessible from another computer in local network (connection refused)

Tags: node.js, pm2, connection-refused

I started pm2 server on my server running ubuntu 20.

To simplify the problem, I created a hello world app using node, like this (/var/www/html/pip/exampleserver.js):

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/');
```

After starting the server with '*pm2 start exampleserver.js*', the server is started, and it works fine when I access it from localhost :

```
wget -qO- localhost:3000
```

Result : "Hello World"

But I get ***ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*** when accessing the page from another computer on the same network (from http://10.200.96.23:3000, either from browser or command line)

However, when I change the script to listen to port 80 and restart pm2, it works just fine from the other computer (from http://10.200.96.23). It shows the result "Hello World".

Here is the result of netstat and ufw status that i've disabled in advance :
[netstat and ufw status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cf3M.png)

Screenshot of error connection refused :
[ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN1FO.png)

I tried other ports, but nothing works other than 80. I don't want to run this server on port 80. What could be the problem?

Comment: port `3000` is not open for the outside world that's why you are getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Port 80 is open by default but not for other ports.
@aRvi is correct, you might need to open port 300 for that to be accessible.

Also `pm2 monitor` will help you see code errors and monitor your application.
This saves my day many times when debugging my codes in PM2

Answer (score 0):

First run

`pm2 list`

and delete the processes with

`pm2 delete [ID]`

Define a new ufw rule

`ufw allow 3000/tcp`

and run your application again.